# Highcharts: StockChart initialization with new Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to initalize a HighStock Chart. If I use this method:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart('StockChart', dataObject);
```

I am getting an error that the rendering div cannot be found. If I use this method:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', dataObject);
```

The Chart is redered as expected. What I am doing wrong in the first method?

regards,
Marko

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mkeuschn/K4Cj6/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create the chart like the first method, you have to delete the first parameter 'StockChart'.
Heres the api: [Highstock api](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart)

So, this should be the code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(dataObject);
```

Working fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/4/)